# Xcode (12.3) Not Responding When Connected To Internet?

Tags: xcode

A few days ago I starting having problems with Xcode hanging. I figured out that disconnecting from wifi fixed the problem and made it run correctly again.

The first day it happened, Xcode was impossible to use while being connected. Since, it's been a bit better, but still hangs often.

I've tried all sorts of things from restarting my computer, to deleting derived data, to reinstalling Xcode. But the issue hasn't resolved.

Please help.